# Creating a polygon from all raster values >0 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I have a raster layer with two values, 0 and 1. I want to create a polygon shape from all the 1 values.

I expected the "raster to vector" tool to achieve this, but this created another grid as a shapefile (i.e. every square of the raster became its own polygon).

Am I using the correct tool and/or the correct settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Menu `Raster / Converstion / Vectorize raster layer` (screenshot 1). On the output layer, apply `Select Features by Expression…` and insert  `"DN" = 0` to the expression editor (screenshot 2), thus selecting all polygons where the raster value is 0: these are the ones you want to delete. Now delete the selected features and you are left just with the polygons representing raster values = 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, the first time I tried using the 'Raster to vector' tool, a set of square polygons were produced. This time it seems to have worked, I must have had the wrong layer attribute selected when using the tool.